# How to register a geofence on phone reboot?

Tags: android, mobile, location, android-broadcastreceiver

I know that I have to use BOOT_COMPLETED and a Broadcast Receiver. But I just need a sample for registering Geofence from Broadcast receiver.I created a Geofence service calss and tried to start it from BroadcastReceiver but it did not work.

```
public class BootCompleteReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver  {


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //Or whatever action your receiver accepts
    if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)){
        Toast.makeText(context , "APP REBBOT RECEIVED" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context , GeoFenceObserversationService.class);
        context.startService(serviceIntent);

      //  GeoFenceObserversationService.getInstant().addGeofences();

    }
}}
```

Here is my service class

Here is My Manifest file.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.cctspl.geofenceex">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"></uses-permission>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"

    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service
        android:name=".GeofenceTransitionsIntentService"
        android:exported="true" />
    <service android:name=".GeoFenceObserversationService"/>
    <receiver android:name=".BootCompleteReceiver"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"></meta-data>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyDcbHjgBC7OTfdrwKjlnag9aQU4_-3IVaw" />
</application>
```

```
public class GeoFenceObserversationService extends Service implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks , GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener , ResultCallback<Status> {
protected static final String TAG = "GeoFenceObserversationService";
protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
protected ArrayList<Geofence> mGeofenceList;
private boolean mGeofencesAdded;
private SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;
private static GeoFenceObserversationService mInstant;
public static GeoFenceObserversationService getInstant(){
    return mInstant;
}
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mInstant = this;
    mGeofenceList = new ArrayList<Geofence>();
    mSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREFERENCES_NAME , MODE_PRIVATE);
    mGeofencesAdded = mSharedPreferences.getBoolean(Constants.GEOFENCES_ADDED_KEY , false);
    populateGeofenceList();
    buildGoogleApiClient();
    addGeofences();
}
public static  final HashMap<String ,LatLng> BAY_AREA_LANDMARKS = new HashMap<String,LatLng>();
static
{
    BAY_AREA_LANDMARKS.put("Rajakilpakkam" , new LatLng(12.915450, 80.150437));

    BAY_AREA_LANDMARKS.put("HANSE GARDEN" , new LatLng(12.911120, 80.156161));

}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

protected  void buildGoogleApiClient() {

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build(); 
             }

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    super.onDestroy();
}

private GeofencingRequest getGeofencingRequest() {
    GeofencingRequest.Builder builder = new GeofencingRequest.Builder();
    builder.setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER);
    builder.addGeofences(mGeofenceList);
    return builder.build();
}
public void populateGeofenceList() {
    for (Map.Entry<String, LatLng> entry : BAY_AREA_LANDMARKS.entrySet()) {
        mGeofenceList.add(new Geofence.Builder()
                // Set the request ID of the geofence. This is a string to identify this
                // geofence.
                .setRequestId(entry.getKey())
                // Set the circular region of this geofence.
                .setCircularRegion(
                        entry.getValue().latitude,
                        entry.getValue().longitude,
                        100
                )

                // Set the expiration duration of the geofence. This geofence gets automatically
                // removed after this period of time.
                .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)

                // Set the transition types of interest. Alerts are only generated for these
                // transition.
                .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)

                .build()
        );

    }
}

public void addGeofences() {
    if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.not_connected), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }


    if(!mGeofenceList.isEmpty()){
        try {
            LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(mGoogleApiClient, getGeofencingRequest(), getGeofencePendingIntent()).setResultCallback(this);
        } catch (SecurityException securityException) {
            securityException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
public void removeGeofences() {
    if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.not_connected), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    try {
        LocationServices.GeofencingApi.removeGeofences(mGoogleApiClient,getGeofencePendingIntent()).setResultCallback(this);
    } catch (SecurityException securityException) {
        securityException.printStackTrace();
    }
}
private PendingIntent getGeofencePendingIntent() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.class);
    return PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

@Override
public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
    if (status.isSuccess()) {
        mGeofencesAdded = !mGeofencesAdded;
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(Constants.GEOFENCES_ADDED_KEY, mGeofencesAdded);
        editor.apply();
    } else {
        String errorMessage = GeofenceErrorMessages.getErrorString(this,status.getStatusCode());
        Log.i("Geofence", errorMessage);
    }}}
```

Thanks in advance.

My LogCat

```
07-28 19:14:09.133 20254-20254/com.cctspl.geofenceex E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                   Process: com.cctspl.geofenceex, PID: 20254
                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.cctspl.geofenceex.GeoFenceObserversationService: java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet.
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2596)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:144)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5154)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:780)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:596)
                                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet.
                                                                       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzod.zzd(Unknown Source)
                                                                       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzoh.zzd(Unknown Source)
                                                                       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzof.zzd(Unknown Source)
                                                                       at com.google.android.gms.location.internal.zzf.addGeofences(Unknown Source)
                                                                       at com.cctspl.geofenceex.GeoFenceObserversationService.addGeofences(GeoFenceObserversationService.java:130)
                                                                       at com.cctspl.geofenceex.GeoFenceObserversationService.onCreate(GeoFenceObserversationService.java:50)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2586)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292) 
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5154) 
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:780) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:596) 
                                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

when you call `startService()`, the `Service` doesn't immediately start. You are just telling Android that you want that `Service` started. Android will start the `Service` when it wants to.

You just need to call `startService()`. I noticed that in `onCreate()` of your `Service` you already establish the geo fences. You don't need to do it again.

Comment: But I have not added the Geofence anywhere else. My service class is not working as well. mGoogleApiClient is always null and not connected. addGeofence is jus t a method.

Comment: Well, you need to get your `Service` working. Your question implies that you have a problem getting it to work on reboot. You should get your `Service` to work first, then solve the reboot problem (if it still exists).

Comment: can you tell me where am I make mistake. I'm a newbie.I hope ur answer will help me

Comment: Ah... I see the problem. You have overidden both `onStartCommand()` and `onStart()`. That's bad. You should just override `onStartCommand()` and do the google api client connect there.

Comment: OK let me try. Thanks for your time

Comment: If you still have problems, post your logcat or explain your problem.

Comment: Im still having a probelm. "GoogleApiClient no yet connected. Try again".

Comment: David Wasser Im not able to add geofence because my mGoogleApiClient is not connected. Its throwing me an error "GoogleApiClient no yet connected. Try again". I hope if this is fixed it will solve my problem.

Comment: Where do you try to connect your client? and where are you getting the error?

Comment: I have updated my log  cat above. This is the error i'm getting. I don't know where I'm committing a mistake.GoogleApiClient object is always no connected. I'm getting this will it enters the addGeofence() method.

Comment: In `onCreate()` you build the client and then try to add Geo fences, before you connect the client. You havent' called `connect()` on the client yet!

Comment: How do I do that??

Comment: `mGoogleApiClient.connect();`